# WinForms raster maps rendering control

Tags: .net, winforms, maps, uicontrol

Consider a map as a set of raster tiles (one set per zoom level). Basically, it's the same how maps are stored in Google Maps, Bing Maps etc.

I need a control which may be used in C# (WinForms) application to render such map and support basic functionality: move, zoom, draw some simple overlays. Again - a control should be very similar to what Google have on maps web-site - but as a WinForms control.

Googling gave me some libraries which looked like an undocumented spaceships. But may be there is something simpler, i could use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

commercial level components are available.

ESRI offers different technologies for GIS mapping we use ArcGis and also MapIt from ESRI, see here:

http://www.esri.com/getting-started/developers/net.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I'm looking for something much simpler and thus - free. Move and zoom are actually the only features required.

Answer (score 0):

If you have googled it then you must know about [GMap.NET](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/). It has some legal issues with Google though.